# References for relative ext-sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I would like to know if there are references for relative ext-sheaves. The only one that I have is the paper of H. Lange (Universal families of extensions, Journal of Algebra 83, 101-112 (1983)), and its references. In particular is it possible to extend the results to (some) non projective varieties ?

Comment: It is unclear from your question what references you are talking about.

Comment: @Sasha  I would like references for the definition, the construction and properties of relative ext-sheaves. I don't know if there is something more recent that Lange's paper.

Comment: Then it is better to explain what do you mean by relative ext-sheaves and which properties you are interested in.

Comment: The definition of Lange is af follows. Let $f:X\to Y$ be a flat projective morphism of noetherian schemes, and $F$, $G$ coherent sheaves on $X$, flat on $Y$. The relative Ext-sheaf $Ext^i_f(F,G)$ is the sheaf on $Y$ associated to the presheaf $$U\mapsto Ext^i_{f^{-1}(U)}(F_{|f^{-1}(U)},G_{|f^{-1}(U)}$$ . In most interesting cases, if the dimension of $Ext^i_{f^{-1}(y)}(F_y,G_y)$

Comment: is independent of $y\in Y$, $Ext^i_f(F,G)$ is a vector bundle with fiber $Ext^i_{f^{-1}(y)}(F_y,G_y)$ at $y$.

Answer (score 4):

For me the most convenient way is to think of these sheaves as of the cohomology sheaves of the object
$$
Rf_*(R\mathcal{H}\mathit{om}(F,G))
$$
of the derived category of $Y$. Using this and the semicontinuity theorem I think you can deduce the desired properties.

Comment: Thank you. I found also after this post an older paper of Altman and Kleiman of 1980 (Compactifying the Picard scheme, section 1),  that contains probably immediately suitable results for me.